# Automatically select the highest quality via js？

Tags: javascript

I want to write a js code to make the video quality on this website automatically select the highest quality.
But I haven't learned js and I've found some relevant code to change it.

For ex： https://www.acfun.cn/v/ac17342395 （for regular video） or https://live.acfun.cn/live/37662640 （in https://live.acfun.cn） （for live video）

// @match              *://www.acfun.cn/v/*   （for regular video）
// @match              *://live.acfun.cn/live/*   （for live video）

```
 model.acfun = {

elements: {

  selectList: {
    get: () => document.querySelector('.quality-panel>li'),
    has: element => ('data-index="0"').test(location.pathname) || element
  }

},

click: element => element.className == 'selected' ? element : element.click(),

handler: model => ('data-index="0"').test(location.pathname) ?
  setTimeout(() => model.click(model.elements.selectList.get()), 1000) :
  true
```

}

Here is what is relevant on this video site.
[image]
[image]
I think I want to automatically select data-index="0" （for regular video） and data-index="3" （for live video） on it. Whatever, automatically select the highest.
How do I change it?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a line to the website so we can test the code before writing a comment?
I am guessing that you need to add the class "selected" to the quality desired and remove this class from whatever li element that is on.
However, without testing it, I can't guarantee that it will work. It might require invoking other functions on the webpage

Comment: @sale108 , thank you for your comment. Please see the content after the edit.

Comment: @renzehe0009 thanks, is the site up? it doesn't load

Comment: hi, I managed to open it today, code below

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for choosing a video that doesn't require login, it simulates a 'click' action on the first item in the list that doesn't require login (meaning, doesn't contain 'go2login' class attribute)

```
// Get all li options (quality options)  
let lis = document.querySelectorAll(".quality-panel li");
    
for(let i=0; i<lis.length; i++){
  // iterate over the lis, choose the first one that doesn't require login
  let elm = lis[i];
  if(elm.className.indexOf("go2login") == -1){
    elm.click();
    break;
  }
}
```

Or this one, if you don't mind logging in, just selecting the first element in the list (since the list of video qualities is ordered from high to low, the first one is the maximal quality)

```
document.querySelectorAll(".quality-panel li:nth-child(1)").click();
```